# Album selector media browser Mac hidden

Tags: macos, mac, finder, photos, catalina

While using the media browser to add photo's to indesign, I think I accidentally dragged the album selector underneath the toolbar of the finder. Now I can't change the photo album I want to select photo's from and the whole media browser has become unusable. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Here there is no album to select from.

[image]

Here there are albums to choose from, it used to look the same way in the photo's section.
[image]